# =CELL("filename") doesn't work with multiple Excel files open at the same time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

**Question**: How do I get the name of the current document in a way that doesn't break down when multiple documents are opened at the same time?

---

I want to write the filename of the current Excel document. `=CELL("filename")` does the job as long as I only have one excel document open at the time, if I have multiple documents open at the same time it breaks down, and one file gets the name of the other file:

[image]

In `B2` I have written `=CELL("filename")`. I would expect each cell to have the name of its own file, but instead both of them have the same filename!

To reproduce

- Open two Excel documents (save them) and write `=CELL("filename")` in both of them. They will both refer to the same file.

I am using Windows 10 and this version of Excel:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CELL` with a slight addition:  specify a cell in each spreadsheet.

So in each, simply use this way of writing the function:

```
=CELL("filename",A1)
```

The reason the other version (just the single parameter, `"filename"`, rather than using both parameters (including a cell in the spreadsheet you wish to get the filename for, "A1" in the case above) does not work as desired is that when not specifying the 2nd parameter, Excel defaults to whatever spreadsheet the last selected cell is/was in.

By specifying a cell in each spreadsheet, you keep that default from happening and Excel cheerfully tells you the name of the file the formula is in. No matter how many files you have open or what/where the currently selected cell is.

*(The cell you give the formula does not matter so long as it is in the same spreadsheet. Since "A1" is easy to type, just use that.)*

Comment: Validated, this works!

Answer (score 1):

The technique of the `CELL` function being used without a specified target to get the desired information (`"address"`, say, or in this case, `"filename"`) gets the information for the selected cell.

Since you cannot select a cell in both at the same time as the "selected cell" from Excel's point of view is the last cell selected in any of a single instance's open files to be THE selected cell, you should see the same value returned in all such uses of the function.

To see your example's "each file have the function return its own name" kind of thing, you need to open two entirely separate instances of Excel. So not "open Excel, open one file, then open the other" but rather "open Excel and one file, then start an entirely separate new instance of Excel and open the second file."

Since you have two completely separate instances open, each regards the other as some foreign thing, sharing nothing between them. For example, open two files in a single instance and you can copy and paste from file to file just as you would from sheet to sheet. Open them in two separate instances and you cannot. You can copy and paste, but it would be like pasting from some utterly different program, Notepad perhaps. Formulas and formatting would not paste, just values, that kind of thing.

To reiterate though, Excel does not see the cell last selected in the first spreadsheet for its formula and see at the same time the last selected cell in the second spreadsheet as the cell to use for the second one's formula. It sees only the literally last selected cell between ALL the files open in its instance.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand. Can you help with a solution? I would like to not 'open completely separate instances' - is there an alternative to the `CELL` function, or way of specifying a target that is bound to the correct file?